# Is there a way to stop infinite retries for custom Kafka Deserializers?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using a custom Kafka deserializer that marshals an object from JSON.

```
val props = Map(
  "bootstrap.servers" -> kafkaQueue.kafkaHost,
  "group.id" -> adapterServer.adapterConfig.kafkaGroup,
  "enable.auto.commit" -> "false",
  "max.poll.records" -> "1",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
  "auto.commit.interval.ms" -> "1000",
  "key.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer",
  "value.deserializer" -> "com.mystuff.CustomJSONDeserializer"
)
new KafkaConsumer[Array[Byte], MyMessage](props)
```

One thing I've seen is that if someone posts bad JSON to the topic, Kafka tries to deserialize it with my custom deserializer--and can't.  The CustomJSONDeserializer throws an exception, but Kafka just keeps trying.

So it just spins infinitely attempting to re-deserialize the bad JSON, essentially getting stuck.  Since this is all happening inside Kafka, I'm not sure how to stop it and tell it to go on to the next message.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

If you catch the exception, your application can seek past the affected message in order to avoid it. There's actually a bug with the 0.10.0.0 consumer that was [masking deserialization errors](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3977) so I'm not sure if earlier versions properly propagate the exception. We'll at least be logging information about the topic, partition, and offset of the message that caused the error as of the upcoming 0.10.0.1 release.